Hugging Face Transformer Model RuntimeError Reshaping Tensor
Background:
we have an inference system composed out of three inference models (Component, Subsumption, Relation) based on the architecture RobertaForSequenceClassification. We are serving it with TorchServe and using Hugging Face Transformers.
Problem:
The system was functioning like two three months ago. Since that it was not active as it was not needed. Now, we want to switch the three models with new ones trained with expanded labeled data.
When we tried to run the system (in its same status as last deployed, models not yet switched), we have been facing problems.
The current problem that we cannot get to its cause is depicted the following error log:
our-model-name  | 2024-10-24T20:57:33,374 [DEBUG] W-9000-component_1.0 org.pytorch.serve.wlm.WorkerThread - Flushing req.cmd PREDICT repeats 1 to backend at: 1729803453374
our-model-name  | 2024-10-24T20:57:33,374 [INFO ] W-9000-component_1.0 org.pytorch.serve.wlm.WorkerThread - Looping backend response at: 1729803453374
our-model-name  | 2024-10-24T20:57:33,375 [INFO ] epollEventLoopGroup-3-4 TS_METRICS - ts_inference_requests_total.Count:1.0|#model_name:subsumption,model_version:default|#hostname:4a9993f30277,timestamp:1729803453
our-model-name  | 2024-10-24T20:57:33,377 [INFO ] epollEventLoopGroup-3-4 TS_METRICS - ts_inference_requests_total.Count:1.0|#model_name:subsumption,model_version:default|#hostname:4a9993f30277,timestamp:1729803453
our-model-name  | 2024-10-24T20:57:33,380 [INFO ] W-9000-component_1.0-stdout MODEL_LOG - Backend received inference at: 1729803453
our-model-name  | 2024-10-24T20:57:33,381 [WARN ] W-9000-component_1.0-stderr MODEL_LOG - Truncation was not explicitly activated but `max_length` is provided a specific value, please use `truncation=True` to explicitly truncate examples to max length. Defaulting to 'longest_first' truncation strategy. If you encode pairs of sequences (GLUE-style) with the tokenizer you can select this strategy more precisely by providing a specific strategy to `truncation`.
our-model-name  | 2024-10-24T20:57:33,381 [INFO ] epollEventLoopGroup-3-7 TS_METRICS - ts_inference_requests_total.Count:1.0|#model_name:component,model_version:default|#hostname:4a9993f30277,timestamp:1729803453
our-model-name  | 2024-10-24T20:57:33,383 [WARN ] W-9000-component_1.0-stderr MODEL_LOG - /home/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/transformers/tokenization_utils_base.py:2829: FutureWarning: The `pad_to_max_length` argument is deprecated and will be removed in a future version, use `padding=True` or `padding='longest'` to pad to the longest sequence in the batch, or use `padding='max_length'` to pad to a max length. In this case, you can give a specific length with `max_length` (e.g. `max_length=45`) or leave max_length to None to pad to the maximal input size of the model (e.g. 512 for Bert).
our-model-name  | 2024-10-24T20:57:33,383 [WARN ] W-9000-component_1.0-stderr MODEL_LOG -   warnings.warn(
our-model-name  | 2024-10-24T20:57:33,383 [INFO ] epollEventLoopGroup-3-4 TS_METRICS - ts_inference_requests_total.Count:1.0|#model_name:subsumption,model_version:default|#hostname:4a9993f30277,timestamp:1729803453
our-model-name  | 2024-10-24T20:57:33,383 [INFO ] epollEventLoopGroup-3-7 TS_METRICS - ts_inference_requests_total.Count:1.0|#model_name:subsumption,model_version:default|#hostname:4a9993f30277,timestamp:1729803453
our-model-name  | 2024-10-24T20:57:33,393 [INFO ] epollEventLoopGroup-3-9 TS_METRICS - ts_inference_requests_total.Count:1.0|#model_name:subsumption,model_version:default|#hostname:4a9993f30277,timestamp:1729803453
our-model-name  | 2024-10-24T20:57:33,394 [DEBUG] W-9002-subsumption_1.0 org.pytorch.serve.wlm.WorkerThread - Flushing req.cmd PREDICT repeats 1 to backend at: 1729803453394
our-model-name  | 2024-10-24T20:57:33,394 [INFO ] W-9002-subsumption_1.0 org.pytorch.serve.wlm.WorkerThread - Looping backend response at: 1729803453394
our-model-name  | 2024-10-24T20:57:33,393 [INFO ] epollEventLoopGroup-3-16 TS_METRICS - ts_inference_requests_total.Count:1.0|#model_name:subsumption,model_version:default|#hostname:4a9993f30277,timestamp:1729803453
our-model-name  | 2024-10-24T20:57:33,398 [INFO ] epollEventLoopGroup-3-16 TS_METRICS - ts_inference_requests_total.Count:1.0|#model_name:subsumption,model_version:default|#hostname:4a9993f30277,timestamp:1729803453
our-model-name  | 2024-10-24T20:57:33,400 [INFO ] epollEventLoopGroup-3-9 TS_METRICS - ts_inference_requests_total.Count:1.0|#model_name:component,model_version:default|#hostname:4a9993f30277,timestamp:1729803453
our-model-name  | 2024-10-24T20:57:33,401 [INFO ] W-9002-subsumption_1.0-stdout MODEL_LOG - Backend received inference at: 1729803453
our-model-name  | 2024-10-24T20:57:33,414 [WARN ] W-9002-subsumption_1.0-stderr MODEL_LOG - Truncation was not explicitly activated but `max_length` is provided a specific value, please use `truncation=True` to explicitly truncate examples to max length. Defaulting to 'longest_first' truncation strategy. If you encode pairs of sequences (GLUE-style) with the tokenizer you can select this strategy more precisely by providing a specific strategy to `truncation`.
our-model-name  | 2024-10-24T20:57:33,415 [WARN ] W-9002-subsumption_1.0-stderr MODEL_LOG - /home/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/transformers/tokenization_utils_base.py:2829: FutureWarning: The `pad_to_max_length` argument is deprecated and will be removed in a future version, use `padding=True` or `padding='longest'` to pad to the longest sequence in the batch, or use `padding='max_length'` to pad to a max length. In this case, you can give a specific length with `max_length` (e.g. `max_length=45`) or leave max_length to None to pad to the maximal input size of the model (e.g. 512 for Bert).
our-model-name  | 2024-10-24T20:57:33,415 [WARN ] W-9002-subsumption_1.0-stderr MODEL_LOG -   warnings.warn(
our-model-name  | 2024-10-24T20:57:33,459 [INFO ] W-9000-component_1.0-stdout MODEL_LOG - Invoking custom service failed.
our-model-name  | 2024-10-24T20:57:33,459 [INFO ] W-9000-component_1.0-stdout MODEL_LOG - Traceback (most recent call last):
our-model-name  | 2024-10-24T20:57:33,459 [INFO ] W-9000-component_1.0-stdout MODEL_LOG -   File "/home/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/ts/service.py", line 135, in predict
our-model-name  | 2024-10-24T20:57:33,459 [INFO ] W-9000-component_1.0-stdout MODEL_LOG -     ret = self._entry_point(input_batch, self.context)
our-model-name  | 2024-10-24T20:57:33,459 [INFO ] W-9000-component_1.0-stdout MODEL_LOG -   File "/home/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/ts/torch_handler/base_handler.py", line 458, in handle
our-model-name  | 2024-10-24T20:57:33,459 [INFO ] W-9000-component_1.0-stdout MODEL_LOG -     output = self.inference(data_preprocess)
our-model-name  | 2024-10-24T20:57:33,460 [INFO ] W-9000-component_1.0-stdout MODEL_LOG -   File "/home/model-server/tmp/models/8d71a33b7b76416181c8a835f70eea9c/generalized_handler.py", line 236, in inference
our-model-name  | 2024-10-24T20:57:33,460 [INFO ] W-9000-component_1.0-stdout MODEL_LOG -     predictions = self.model(input_ids_batch, attention_mask_batch)
our-model-name  | 2024-10-24T20:57:33,460 [INFO ] W-9000-component_1.0-stdout MODEL_LOG -   File "/home/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 1553, in _wrapped_call_impl
our-model-name  | 2024-10-24T20:57:33,460 [INFO ] W-9000-component_1.0-stdout MODEL_LOG -     return self._call_impl(*args, **kwargs)
our-model-name  | 2024-10-24T20:57:33,460 [INFO ] W-9000-component_1.0-stdout MODEL_LOG -   File "/home/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 1562, in _call_impl
our-model-name  | 2024-10-24T20:57:33,460 [INFO ] W-9000-component_1.0-stdout MODEL_LOG -     return forward_call(*args, **kwargs)
our-model-name  | 2024-10-24T20:57:33,461 [INFO ] W-9000-component_1.0-stdout MODEL_LOG -   File "/home/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/transformers/models/roberta/modeling_roberta.py", line 1339, in forward
our-model-name  | 2024-10-24T20:57:33,461 [INFO ] W-9000-component_1.0-stdout MODEL_LOG -     outputs = self.roberta(
our-model-name  | 2024-10-24T20:57:33,461 [INFO ] W-9000-component_1.0-stdout MODEL_LOG -   File "/home/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 1553, in _wrapped_call_impl
our-model-name  | 2024-10-24T20:57:33,461 [INFO ] W-9000-component_1.0-stdout MODEL_LOG -     return self._call_impl(*args, **kwargs)
our-model-name  | 2024-10-24T20:57:33,461 [INFO ] W-9000-component_1.0-stdout MODEL_LOG -   File "/home/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 1562, in _call_impl
our-model-name  | 2024-10-24T20:57:33,461 [INFO ] W-9000-component_1.0-stdout MODEL_LOG -     return forward_call(*args, **kwargs)
our-model-name  | 2024-10-24T20:57:33,461 [INFO ] W-9000-component_1.0-stdout MODEL_LOG -   File "/home/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/transformers/models/roberta/modeling_roberta.py", line 976, in forward
our-model-name  | 2024-10-24T20:57:33,462 [INFO ] W-9000-component_1.0-stdout MODEL_LOG -     encoder_outputs = self.encoder(
our-model-name  | 2024-10-24T20:57:33,463 [INFO ] W-9000-component_1.0-stdout MODEL_LOG -   File "/home/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 1553, in _wrapped_call_impl
our-model-name  | 2024-10-24T20:57:33,464 [INFO ] W-9000-component_1.0-stdout MODEL_LOG -     return self._call_impl(*args, **kwargs)
our-model-name  | 2024-10-24T20:57:33,464 [INFO ] W-9000-component_1.0-stdout MODEL_LOG -   File "/home/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 1562, in _call_impl
our-model-name  | 2024-10-24T20:57:33,464 [INFO ] W-9000-component_1.0-stdout MODEL_LOG -     return forward_call(*args, **kwargs)
our-model-name  | 2024-10-24T20:57:33,464 [INFO ] W-9000-component_1.0-stdout MODEL_LOG -   File "/home/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/transformers/models/roberta/modeling_roberta.py", line 631, in forward
our-model-name  | 2024-10-24T20:57:33,464 [INFO ] W-9000-component_1.0-stdout MODEL_LOG -     layer_outputs = layer_module(
our-model-name  | 2024-10-24T20:57:33,464 [INFO ] W-9000-component_1.0-stdout MODEL_LOG -   File "/home/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 1553, in _wrapped_call_impl
our-model-name  | 2024-10-24T20:57:33,464 [INFO ] W-9000-component_1.0-stdout MODEL_LOG -     return self._call_impl(*args, **kwargs)
our-model-name  | 2024-10-24T20:57:33,464 [INFO ] W-9000-component_1.0-stdout MODEL_LOG -   File "/home/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 1562, in _call_impl
our-model-name  | 2024-10-24T20:57:33,465 [INFO ] W-9000-component_1.0-stdout MODEL_LOG -     return forward_call(*args, **kwargs)
our-model-name  | 2024-10-24T20:57:33,465 [INFO ] W-9000-component_1.0-stdout MODEL_LOG -   File "/home/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/optimum/bettertransformer/models/encoder_models.py", line 300, in forward
our-model-name  | 2024-10-24T20:57:33,465 [INFO ] W-9000-component_1.0-stdout MODEL_LOG -     attention_mask = torch.reshape(attention_mask, (attention_mask.shape[0], attention_mask.shape[-1]))
our-model-name  | 2024-10-24T20:57:33,465 [INFO ] W-9000-component_1.0-stdout MODEL_LOG - RuntimeError: shape '[16, 256]' is invalid for input of size 1048576
our-model-name  | 2024-10-24T20:57:33,471 [INFO ] W-9000-component_1.0 ACCESS_LOG - /172.21.0.4:45170 "POST /predictions/component HTTP/1.1" 503 174
our-model-name  | 2024-10-24T20:57:33,471 [INFO ] W-9000-component_1.0 TS_METRICS - Requests5XX.Count:1.0|#Level:Host|#hostname:4a9993f30277,timestamp:1729803453
our-model-name  | 2024-10-24T20:57:33,472 [DEBUG] W-9000-component_1.0 org.pytorch.serve.job.RestJob - Waiting time ns: 56128789, Inference time ns: 154039067
our-model-name  | 2024-10-24T20:57:33,472 [INFO ] W-9000-component_1.0 ACCESS_LOG - /172.21.0.4:45204 "POST /predictions/component HTTP/1.1" 503 154
our-model-name  | 2024-10-24T20:57:33,472 [INFO ] W-9000-component_1.0 TS_METRICS - Requests5XX.Count:1.0|#Level:Host|#hostname:4a9993f30277,timestamp:1729803453


Env:
Pipfile:
[[source]]
url = "https://pypi.org/simple"
verify_ssl = true
name = "pypi"

[packages]
transformers = "4.46.0"
torchserve = "*"
torch-model-archiver = "*"
torch-workflow-archiver = "*"
optimum = "*"
captum = "*"

[dev-packages]

[requires]
python_version = "3.8"


config.properties:
inference_address=http://0.0.0.0:8080
models= {\
  "component": {\
    "1.0": {\
        "defaultVersion": true,\
        "marName": "model-component.mar",\
        "minWorkers": 1,\
        "maxWorkers": 3,\
        "batchSize": 16,\
        "maxBatchDelay": 1000,\
        "responseTimeout": 120\
    }\
  },\
  "subsumption": {\
    "1.0": {\
        "defaultVersion": true,\
        "marName": "model-subsumption.mar",\
        "minWorkers": 1,\
        "maxWorkers": 3,\
        "batchSize": 16,\
        "maxBatchDelay": 1000,\
        "responseTimeout": 120\
    }\
  },\
  "relation": {\
    "1.0": {\
        "defaultVersion": true,\
        "marName": "model-relation.mar",\
        "minWorkers": 1,\
        "maxWorkers": 3,\
        "batchSize": 16,\
        "maxBatchDelay": 1000,\
        "responseTimeout": 120\
    }\
  }\
}

In the config.json files that are zipped into the models .mar files, there is
"transformers_version": "4.28.1"

I wanted to mention it in case this indicates a problem, as the pipfile mentions 4.46.0 as transformers version. I already tested changing the version in all config.json to 4.46.0 but the problem was not solved.
As I mentioned, the code as it is now was functioning a couple months ago, so we are thinking it should be Lib versions problem?
We would be happy to hear any insights that might help solve the problem :)
